# replace all occurance of a character in jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace `"` with `\"`

I am using

```
content.replace(/"/g,'\\"')
```

Now I want to do this only when `"` occurs **without** `\` before it

For example

I want `"title"` to be replaced as `\"title\"` 
But if the string is already `\"title\"` I don't want to replace `"` to `\"`

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? It's almost like you're trying to escape a string through code. There may be a better way

Comment: Some users have the knowledge to add \ if they use ", but some won't do it. That's why

Comment: why they know they need to add \ ? wouldn't it be better that all know they don't have to do this and you then allwais escape this char?

Comment: yeah, but user education is not that easy to do :(  its better to handle it if there is a simple way

Comment: i don't know your form but i would not expect to escape my input in a form. I would expect the application to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `content.replace(/["]/g, "\\$&")`.

Example:

```
var content = '"title", \"title", \"title\"';
content.replace(/["]/g, "\\$&");

Output: '\"title\", \"title\", \"title\"'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It won't work. I have test it in my browser and it still replace `"` with `\"`

Answer (score 1):

```
content.replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, '$1\\"');
```

Comment: test now please, and sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this works for me

```
var content = 'hello"world\"'

content.replace(/\\"/g,'"').replace(/"/g,'\\"')
```

This logs

```
"hello\"world\""
```

Comment: sorry, but don't you asked with a regex? This was the difficulty. ahahaha

Comment: You mean... `.replace(/\\"/g,'"').replace(/"/g,'\\"')`

Comment: have fun with imputs like: `'hello"world\\\\"'`

Comment: No any solution is fine for me as long as it does what I need :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan haha